# Поисковая система по нескольким таблицам

Tags: php

Как организовать поисковую систему из нескольких таблиц с разным количеством полей?

в даном скрипте ошибка из-за разного количества полей в таблицах:

```
  $search=$_POST["search"];
    $products = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id,title FROM 
categories WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'
     UNION SELECT id,title FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'
     UNION SELECT id,name, title_cont,zagolovok FROM products 
WHERE name 
LIKE '%$search%' OR  title_cont LIKE '%$search%'");
    while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($products)){

        printf('<p><a href="index.php?id='.$array['id'].'">'.$array['title'].'</a>');
        }
```

Comment: Сделать число столбцов одинаковым можно, например, так: `...UNION SELECT id,title, 0 AS title_cont, '' AS zagolovok...` только может быть вы не этого действительно хотите? Чего вы хотите таким запросом добиться?

Comment: хочу сделать поисковую систему которая будет выводить ответ из разных таблиц и полей на один запрос

Comment: В таком случае @BOPOH прав: сделайте так, чтобы все запросы выводили одинаковое кол-во полей. Просто добавьте пустые...

Comment: cyadvert , есть возможность сделать поиск по сайту не меняя структуру таблиц?

Comment: А не надо менять структуру таблиц...

Comment: cyadvert, понял спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить виртуальных ("пустых") колонок в запрос.

Типа такого:

```
SELECT id, title,'','' FROM categories WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'
UNION
SELECT id, title,'','' FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'
UNION
SELECT id, name, title_cont, zagolovok FROM products WHERE name 
LIKE '%$search%' OR  title_cont LIKE '%$search%'"
```

`,'',''` добавляет по две пустые колонки в первые два `SELECT`, таким образом получается, что во всех 3 `SELECT` одинаковое кол-во столбцов...

Comment: ДА это то что надо=)

Comment: еще один вопрос, есть ли смысл делать автозаполнение с подсказками на такой поиск?

Comment: не понял... в смысле на сайте в поле поиска? Если "да", то это зависит от нескольких факторов: проекта, объема данных, желания разработчика возиться, надоедливости клиента... :) Но автозаполнение всегда выглядит круто... Лишь бы не тормозило :)

Comment: к нескольким полям одной таблицы сделать не проблема, а вот к нескольким таблицам ума не приложу как)

Comment: не совсем понимаю о чем ты... на сайте-то поле поиска одно? куда человек впечатывает поисковый критерий...